# Python classes and the __init___ constructor, how to make a list variable?

Tags: python, list, class, constructor, getter-setter

Hi I am creating a class that has a shopping list. The code seems to work but I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly. Am I meant to put shopping = [] in the constructor, what does that do?
Many thanks in advance

```
class Shopping:
    def __init__(self, shopping = []): 
        self.__shopping = []

   
    def set_shopping(self, shopping): 
          self.__shopping  = shopping
    def get_shopping(self): 
        return self.__shopping

shoppinglist = Shopping()
shoppinglist = ['apples', 'pears', 'bread']
```

Comment: shopping = [] in the constructor creates an empty list which is unique to the instance so, yes, your approach seems correct. If you had declared the list attribute outside the constructor it would have been common to all instances of that class.

Comment: oh great thanks, would i need to put shopping [] in the setter too? As i only have the shopping variable and no list in the setter

Comment: shopping **is** the list, you should not declare it more than once. Currently you cannot add an article in your list, you can just set the whole list. So you could add something like self.__shopping.append(newArticle) in another method if you wish.

Comment: Got it! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example :

```
class Shopping:
    def __init__(self, shopping = []): 
        self.__shopping = []
    
    def set_shopping(self, shopping): 
          self.__shopping  = shopping
    
    def get_shopping(self): 
        return self.__shopping
    
    def add_article(self, article): 
          self.__shopping.append(article)

    def get_article(self, index): 
          return self.__shopping[index]

    shoppinglist = Shopping()
    shoppinglist.set_shopping(['apples', 'pears', 'bread'])
    shoppinglist.add_article('oranges')
    shoppinglist.get_article(0) #==> 'apples'
    shoppinglist.get_article(3) #==> 'oranges'
```